# How resolve ~ (home) in remote uri?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I wonder if Vscode can resolve folder uris like: "vscode-remote://ssh-remote+cnotch/~/myFolderInMyHome"?
I never needed to use absolute path with ssh tools like `ssh` or `scp` and seems like it should work with vscode too.

Comment: can you use the environment variable `HOME`

Comment: Tried ``Powershell > code --folder-uri "vscode-remote://ssh-remote+cnotch/`$HOME/myFolderInMyHome"`` that doesn't work.